# How should I handle a question that is self-answered in the comments?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Today I was looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41839317/my-uiview-is-permanently-black). In case it's deleted (one option) it was answered in the comments by the questioner. He made a fairly common mistake, which I believe isn't at issue but I wouldn't have looked at this if I knew there was an answer.

I made this comment:

> Please either post your solution as an answer (if you feel others may
>   benefit from it) or delete the question. Either one works well on this
>   site - but leaving things unanswered like this (with the solution in
>   the comments) does not.

Is this the correct way to handle this?

Comment: Sounds like a chance to maybe obtain(or lose) some rep

Comment: Basically, you've handled this correctly so far. If there's no response after a couple days (or hours, if you wish), if you come back to check, then you could opt to post your own answer. Or you could just do it now.